# How to redefine a pair in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working a lot with pairs in c++ these days so I want to do next:

Instead of:

```
pair<int, int> p;
cin >> p.first >> p.second;
```

I want to write:

```
pair<int, int> p;
cin >> p.x >> p.y;
```

I tried #define first x and similar things but it doesn't work. How to redefine this?

Answer (score 0):

Just define your own template struct with `x` and `y` members. Just like `std::pair`, just with different member names. Then use your own struct instead of `std::pair`.

Comment: Or just `struct point { int x, y }; point p;`.

Comment: @melpomene assuming the types are always `int`. A template gives more flexibility and matches `std::pair` closer.